# undefined method `new' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

This question's name has been used but this question is completely different. In **localhost:3000/forums/new**, it says this:

**undefined method `new' for nil:NilClass**

my forums_controller.rb:

```
 class ForumsController < ApplicationController
     def index
     end

     def forum
     end

     def new
         @forum = forum.new
     end

     def create
         @forum = forum.new (forum_params)
     end

     private

     def forum_params
         params.require(:forum).permit(:title, :text)
     end
 end
```

my new.html.erb (under view>forums):

```
 <h1>New Forum</h1>

 = render 'forum'

 = link_to "Back", root_path
```

my index.html.erb under view>forums is completely empty.
my application controller:

```
 class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   protect_from_forgery with: :exception
 end
```

_forum.html.erb:

```
 = simple_form_for @forum, html: { multipart: true } do |f|
   - if @forum.errors.any?
     #errors
       %h2
       = pluralize(@forum.errors.count, "error")
       perevented this Forum for saving
       %ul
         - @forum.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
           %li= msg

   .forum-group
     = f.input :title, input_html { class: 'forum-control' }

   .forum-group
     = f.input :text, input_html { class: 'forum-control' }

 = f.button :submit,class: "btn btn-primary"
```

Anyone know how to solve this?
If there is any code missing, please comment and I will add it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you wanted to write something like

```
Forum.new
```

not

```
forum.new
```

where `forum` is obviously is `nil` as far as you defined `forum` as

```
def forum
end
```

And I hope that you have defined `Forum` model in your application

Comment: also in the create method you will probably want `@forum = Forum.create (forum_params)` instead of what you have now.